# How to set an exact date and time in material ui date time picker component using selenium and java?

Tags: java, selenium, material-ui, datetimepicker

The website I'm working with has an identical datetimepicker component to `MobileDateTimePicker` [shown in this page](https://mui.com/components/date-time-picker/#responsiveness).

I can get past the date selection by using xpath of the exact day I want in calendar view however that doesn't work for the hours/minutes in the analog clock view shown after selecting a date.

Is there a specific way to select hours/minutes in material ui date time picker?

(Manually clicking on exact hours/minutes get the job done but selenium is throwing `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted` error when when clicking on span class for the respective hour/minute(s) shown in analog clock.)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried by myself, hit the same exception. There is another div that would recieve the click. Tried click using Actions and JavascriptExecutor but no success. The only solution left is to sendkeys direct to the input.

Comment: I believe the answer here is that your developers (or you) need to add an `id` attribute or some other unique identifier so that you could create the appropriate XPath to locate the specific component. Remember, the main purpose of these web elements it to provide a function or service, not to be testable by Selenium or some other framework. YOU need to build the elements in the right way that serve your purpose.